# Add element count to end of each line in a file containing sets

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have a file which contains sets of data and I need to add the total amount of lines to each line/record.

File Example:

```
set1-open
record
record
record
record
set1-close
set2-open
record
record
record
record
record
set2-close
```

and so on...

I would like to have:

```
set1-open
record 4
record 4
record 4
record 4
set1-close
set2-open
record 5
record 5
record 5
record 5
record 5
set2-close
```

I'm writing this in Shell, so sed would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -r '/open/{x;s/.*/0/;x};//,/close/{//b;x;:a;s/9(#*)$/#\1/;ta;s/$/:0123456789/;s/(.)(#*):.*\1(.).*/\3\2/;y/#/0/;x;G;s/\n/ /}' file
```

Clear the hold space (HS) on encountering the start of block of records and prep it with a counter set to zero. Within a block of records use the HS to keep a counter which is incremented and then a copy appended to each record.